# How can I add different filters to different columns in Kendo Grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid with multiple columns, one that is based off an int property and another that is based on the string property.

I am trying to filter the columns with different operators and have added the following code:

```
.Filterable(ftb => ftb.Extra(false)
.Operators(op => op
    .ForNumber(num => num
            .Clear()
            .IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(">="))
    .ForString(str =>
        str.Clear()
            .Contains("Contains"))))
```

However, for some reason the above doesn't work. What is the best method to have different operators on different columns? Can I specify a filter operator on certain columns?

Is there a way to specify for example 3 operators on all but one column, and have that special column use a different operator?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to define the filter options for the grid, and then for each column individually which seems to override the grid settings.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SomeType>()
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.StringProperty1)
                .Filterable(f => f.Operators(op => op.ForString(str =>
                        str.Clear().Contains("Contains1234"))
                ));
        columns.Bound(c => c.StringProperty2);
        columns.Bound(c => c.IntProperty);
    })
    .Filterable(f => f.Operators(op => op

            .ForNumber(num =>
                num.Clear()
                .IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(">="))
            .ForString(str =>
                str.Clear()
                .Contains("Contains5678"))
    ))
    .Name("Grid")
)
```

In the example above, `StringProperty1` would get the `Contains1234` filter and `StringProperty2` would get the `Contains5678` filter.